# What does the getcontext system call (ucontext.h) really do?

Tags: c, operating-system, posix, ucontext

I took operating systems last year, during which I used user contexts (defined in the header `ucontext.h`) to implement a thread scheduler (in which each thread simulated a process) for a project. I'm taking part in a lecture and will talk about user contexts, and it just occurred to me that, despite having done this project last year, I don't really understand what exactly the `getcontext` system call actually does.

The [man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcontext.3.html) for `getcontext` states that it

> initializes the structure pointed at by ucp to the currently active context."

It also states, for the argument to `setcontext`, that if the ucp argument

> was obtained by a call of getcontext(), program execution continues as if this call just returned.

Okay, so I understand that.

So here's what I'm confused about. Typically, for the way I learned it, to perform a context switch, one would initialize the `ucontext_t` struct and swap/set it as such:

```
ucontext_t ucp;
ucontext_t oucp;
getcontext(&ucp);

// Initialize the stack_t struct in the ucontext_t struct
ucp.uc_stack.ss_sp = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
ucp.uc_stack.ss_size = STACK_SIZE;
ucp.uc_stack.ss_flags = 0;

ucp.uc_link = /* some other context, or just NULL */;

// Don't block any signals in this context
sigemptyset(&ucp.uc_sigmask);
// Assume that fn is a function that takes 0 arguments and returns void
makecontext(&ucp, fn, 0);

// Perform the context switch. Function 'fn' will be active now
swapcontext(&oucp, &ucp);
// alternatively: setcontext(&ucp);
```

If I omit `getcontext` in smaller programs, nothing interesting happens. In somewhat larger programs in which there is more context switching via user contexts, I get a segmentation fault that is only resolved by adding `getcontext` back in.

What exactly does `getcontext` do? Why can't I just allocate a `ucontext_t` struct, initialize it by initializing the `uc_stack` and `uc_sigmask` fields, and calling `makecontext` without the `getcontext`? Is there some necessary initialization that `getcontext` performs that `makecontext` does not perform?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I looked at the GNU libc implementation for ucontext on x86/linux architectures, so, there might be different implementations for which the following does not hold.

The [GNU libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Non_002dLocal-Exits) states that:

> The ucp parameter passed to the makecontext shall be initialized by a call to getcontext.

If you look at mcontext_t in glibc/sysdeps/unix/linux/x86/sys/ucontext.h there is a pointer to the floating point state (fpregset_t fpregs) that is initialized in getcontext() and dereferenced again in setcontext(). However, it is not initialized using makecontext(). I did a quick test with GDB and I got a segfault in setcontext() when trying to dereference the pointer to the floating point context in a ucontext_t struct not initialized by getcontext():

> => 0x00007ffff784308c <+44>:  fldenv (%rcx)